# How to make Application's windows always display in the same Monitor when having multiple displays?

Tags: display

I've successfully got two monitors running on a 2012 Mac Mini. But how do I get each screen to have it's own *identity* ? That is, how do I get windows 2-3 open on monitor A, and windows 4-6 open on monitor B?

They should be able somehow to have separate and distinct displays, right?

Answer (score 1):

hold the "control" key and click the App's icon on the dock, from the context menu, choice the "Options" and you can set the app keep opening on which display you want.[image]